# Is the use of javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport obsolete?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags, taglib

I'm asking if today the most of the work on JSP pages is possible with only JSTL, Spring tags etc. So, in this context, is the use of `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagSupport` obsolete?

Answer (score 1):

**[TagSupport](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagSupport.html) is not obsolete.**  It's meant to be used as the base class for new tag handlers. It is the very foundation of the handlers you mentioned from JSTL or Spring, for example:

- [JSTL `<c:out>` tag](http://tomcat.apache.org/taglibs/standard/apidocs/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/el/core/OutTag.html):

[image]

- [Spring `<spring:form>` tag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/FormTag.html):

[image]

There are lots of useful JSP tags out there that can be used out of the box to provide common functionality and allow you to perform common tasks without reinventing the wheal, but they are all based on classes and interfaces like the `TagSupport`. **That's the mechanism to create custom tags.**

If you didn't need to create your own tags up till now then you are lucky. At some point though you might need to create your own special tags and `TagSupport` will prove very useful.